# Deserializing string returns null

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a string (71499 characters) and I'm always getting null when I tried to deserialize it. When I use a string with a smaller character count, it works correctly. I've have the following:

[jsonstring](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1f806ac104ce47e2b41acdbaec0c41a9)

```
string longSerializedString = "" // 71499 characters long
MyObject data = null;
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(longSerializedString); // data = null
```

No exceptions are thrown and the deserialized result is always null. How would I go about deserializing a very long string, such as the one I'm using?

Comment: This is a lot of json, there is a lot of classes involved, none of them are shown. i would suggest commenting most of this out, and starting small with something that works and working your way up until it doesn't . this is not really a good fit for stack overflow in its current format

Comment: Without knowing how your "MyObject" class looks like, it's hard to say what's the problem.

Comment: `MyObject` is a very large class which is why I haven't posted it. So the issue could by with `MyObject` and not the character count of the string?